# How to extract following lines after encountering a string in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script

For example, I have a text file names

`> "result_merge_file.txt"`

which holds logs of 10 different files which are merged and held in that file.

now I am trying to

> extract a certain section

from that merged logfile "result_merge_file.txt" and send it to another file say

> "result_after_Extraction.txt"

`> extract a certain section looks like following`

```
PerformanceINFO                                             
            UVM_INFO_PERF ****NIB-FIB Axis Interface Per-packet Performance Report****                                             
             interface_name            : NIB-FIB,                                             
             date                      : NAN,                                             
             interface_description     : injection,                                             
             port_number               : 0,                                             
             clock_period (ps)         : 4850,                                             
             number_of_diff_packets    : 10,                                             
             payload_sizes (bytes)     : {312, 1100, 1132, 1404, 1666, 3100, 3610, 4998, 7922, 8544, }                                             
             packet_datarate (bits/clk): {116, 127, 125, 120, 119, 121, 124, 121, 124, 121, }
`
```

what I tried so far is

```
grep -A3 -P '^PerformanceINFO$' temp_log.txt > result_after_Extraction.txt
```

but gives blank results

Answer (score 1):

The `PerformanceINFO` line is not ended with INFO, it has trailing spaces.

So, get rid of the `$` sign, or

```
grep -A3 '^PerformanceINFO\s\+$'
```

Comment: can I extract the following rows
payload_sizes (bytes)     : {312, 1100, 1132, 1404, 1666, 3100, 3610, 4998, 7922, 8544, }                                             
packet_datarate (bits/clk): {116, 127, 125, 120, 119, 121, 124, 121, 124, 121, }


on to .csv file